# Pull Entire column from different sheet without zero's

Tags: multiple-columns

how to pull column from different sheet..

I've a sheet using the below formula to get the column(n rows) from Sheet1 to Sheet2 however I'm getting zeros after nth row. How to avoid zeros here ??

=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1)),Sheet1!C:C,"")

I'm doing the same for A,B,C columns to get data from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Any better formula ?

Answer (score 0):

zeros are coming because the original column doesn't have data after nth row. for example if zero occur at 301 for column c means data in the column C has values upto 300 rows.

we can avoid this issue in two ways

1. stop copying formula after you get zeros
   or
2. Put a unique word in the formula (here stopcopying)
3. `=IF(LEN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C12)),Sheet1!C:C,""))=0,"stopcopying",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1)),Sheet1!C:C,""))`
4. Find "Stopcopying" keyword and replace without giving any word ( ctrl F and R)

Comment: This doesnt work in my current situation. Is there any way to pull entire column from a different sheet ??

Comment: change the sheet name  and column as per your requirement. i gave just a reference

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can see and this answered my question:

```
=FILTER($B:$E,(B:B<>""))
```